# As of current versions, would any of these setups pass safetynet checks?

Tags: kernel, lineageos, magisk

Would these pass?

OP3T + LineageOS + Kernel that doesn't show bootloader unlocked status?
and also
OP3T + LineageOS + Kernel that doesn't show bootloader unlocked status + Magisk?

I'm currently on Marshmallow and am considering upgrading to 7 (through lineage) but I want to make sure I can pass checks because some apps are a royal pain to use/install if I can't pass the check.

(I would likely not be using Xposed at this time, so I'll leave that out of the equation).

Comment: Main reason for safety net failing is SU/rooted phone. So if you plan to root phone safety net can't be passed, actually you can pass it with su hide or magisk but that is game of cat and mouse. Xposed itself isn't a problem I think but since it requires a root you see a connection there. ROM and kernel shouldn't make any problems with safety net.

Comment: That's not correct.  Safetynet trips for an unlocked bootloader.  Kernels can prevent this by lying about the bootloader state.

Comment: Well then you have answered your own question :)

Comment: I have not answered my own question because I still do not know if LineageOS passes safetynet provided you use a kernel that does not report the bootloader being unlocked.  It can still fail without that specific trip.

Comment: Oh, well then I think it's best to test it yourself or ask on xda one plus forums

Comment: That's not really helpful.  I asked here.  The XDA topics are too specialized.  Would I ask on the rom thread, kernel thread, device thread, etc...

Comment: Make a new thread in Q&A subforum for OP3T

Answer (score 0):

I have been using my OnePlus 3T with LineageOS 14.1 without su and with a custom-built kernel for half a year now. SafetyNet passes, AndroidPay works.